# VMWare ESXi mounts datastore with different path after reboot

Tags: esxi

I know that ESXi is meant to be run 24/7 (mostly) but whenever I reboot (whether it's for maintenance or just because I'm fed up of the racket it makes), the datastore "Mandatory VMs" which is a 100GB HDD remounts with a different file path to what it had the previous time ESXi was running. This results with me having to re-register the VMs from that datastore. This means that my pfsense router will not start on boot as it is not found. I did copy them from my previous datastore and i clicked "I moved it" for both.

Here you can see pfsense has been re-registered but but the other one still remains:

[image]